# How to configure router to allow internal ip to be accessed

Tags: router, ip

My local IP address is `192.168.0.105`

I created port forwarding on my D-Link router as shown.

[image]

I then start a local sinatra server on `127.0.0.1:4567`

[image]

But I can't see it via the external IP address, using

http://24.61.999.999:4567   # Note, last two "999" IP numbers hidden for security

What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't port forwarded 4567 which you are using in your http request ...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be opening UDP port 5678 from the outside, while expecting to access it via HTTP (which would normally only use TCP). Change that to TCP.

Also, you run the Sinatra server on the localhost (127.0.0.1) interface of the internal machine. You should probably change that to 192.168.0.105 as otherwise it will not be accessible from outside of the local host.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that you bind to `127.0.0.1` is by definition localhost-only (loopback traffic isn't routed anywhere).

If you want to make your service available to the outside, you have to make it listen on the IP address that points to your router (in your case `192.168.0.105`).

Besides, you would also want to narrow down the port range in your forward declaration, because you could accidentally open ports this way that aren't supposed to be accessed from the outside.